# Adding strings, first, first + second, etc

Tags: python, arrays

Program has to be able adding strings from the list and output them in sequence but in the way:

```
1 string
1 + 2 string
1 + 2 + 3 string ...
```

```
def spacey(array):
    pass
    e = ""
    i = ""
    m = []
    
    for e in list(array):
        i += e

    return (i)
```

This gives me output of all strings added together like:

```
Thisismyquestionforyou
```

but it requires to work like:

```
This
Thisis
thisismy...
```

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: You need to print each time you append a string, not only at the end.

Comment: What specifically is the issue? Have you done any debugging? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 3):

You can use `itertools.accumulate` to do this easily

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> s = "This is my question for you"
>>> list(accumulate(s.split()))
['This', 'Thisis', 'Thisismy', 'Thisismyquestion', 'Thisismyquestionfor', 'Thisismyquestionforyou']
```

Comment: This is nice but it gives me:

    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: I have defined `s` as a string. If you already have a list, invoke `list(accumulate(s))`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```py
>>> def foo(list):
...     s=""
...     for i in list:
...             print(s+i)
...             s+=i
...
```

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't give me list output:
I need it in [1string, 12string, 123string]

Even if I output it in list way it doesn't work like that.

Comment: @Vidar567 create a another param like, `def foo(list, result)` and instead of `print(s+i)`, append it to the `result` list by `result.append(s+i)`. When calling the function, pass along a empty list for the `result` param

Answer (score 0):

problem is that you are setting the whole string and then outputting it

it should look like this

```
for e in list(array):
    i += e
    print(i)
```

that will print it the way you want, but obviously you cant return the full string, and then outputting it. And just a reminder to Name your Variables acordingly

```
for subString in list(array)
    fullString += subString
    print(fullString)
```

or something like that, way more clear and provides all information one need to debug

Answer (score 0):

mylist = ['This', 'is', 'myquestion', 'for', 'you']

```
idx = 1
for _ in range(len(mylist)):
    print(' '.join(mylist[0:idx]))
    idx += 1
```

Comment: If you remove the space between single quotes, it will match exactly what you're after

Answer (score 0):

Thats true thanks,

```
>>return list(a)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

My output should be in the list [1string, 12string, 123string]
Now my code is like:

```
def spacey(array):
pass
e = ""
i = ""
m = []
a = ''


for e in list(array):
    a = print(e + i)
    i += e

return list(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your function is returning only the last element. You can append all the elements to a list.

```
def func(arr):
  e = "" 
  i = "" 
  m = []
  for e in arr:
    i += e
    m.append(i)
  return m

func(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
```

output: ['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd', 'abcde']